# Find $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{xt^x}{1+t^x}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I have to find $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \displaystyle\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{xt^x}{1+t^x}dt$. I know the answer is $\ln(2)$.

To prove it i tried to compare $\dfrac{xt^x}{1+t^x}$ to $\dfrac{1}{1+t}$ because $\displaystyle\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{1}{1+t}dt = \ln(2)$ but it didn't work.

Moreover, we have that $1-\displaystyle\frac{t^x}{1+t^x}= \dfrac{1}{1+t^x}$ and therefore that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{xt^x}{1+t^x}dt=x\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^1 1-\dfrac{1}{1+t^x} \right)$ but it doesn't seem useful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know dominated or monotone convergence?

Comment: As in your other question, think about Euler integral respresntation of harmonic numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we substitute $u = t^x$ (so $t = u^{1/x}$), then $\mathrm du = x t^{x-1}\,\mathrm dt$, so we get $$\int_0^1 \frac{xt^x}{1+t^x}\,\mathrm dt = \int_0^1 \frac{u^{1/x}}{1+u}\,\mathrm du.$$
As an upper bound, $u^{1/x} < 1$ for $u \in [0,1]$ and $x>0$, so
$$
   \int_0^1 \frac{u^{1/x}}{1+u}\,\mathrm du \le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+u}\,\mathrm du = \ln 2
$$
and therefore the limit is also bounded by $\ln 2$.

As a lower bound, first consider the integral on the interval $[\epsilon,1]$  for some $\epsilon>0$. Since $u^{1/x}$ grows with $u$, we have $u^{1/x} \ge \epsilon^{1/x}$ for all $u \in [\epsilon,1]$; therefore
$$
   \int_0^1 \frac{u^{1/x}}{1+u}\,\mathrm du \ge \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{u^{1/x}}{1+u}\,\mathrm du \ge \int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{\epsilon^{1/x}}{1+u}\,\mathrm du \ge \epsilon^{1/x}(\ln 2 - \ln(1+\epsilon)).
$$
As $x \to \infty$, $\frac1x \to 0$, so $\epsilon^{1/x} \to 1$, so this lower bound converges to $\ln 2 - \ln(1+\epsilon)$.

Therefore, for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $$\ln2 -\ln(1+\epsilon) \le \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{u^{1/x}}{1+u}\,\mathrm du \le \ln 2$$ which can only be true if the limit is $\ln 2$.

Comment: I have a question. When you say that since $\epsilon^{1/x} \to 1$ as $x \to +\infty$ if follows that if $x$ is large enough we have $\epsilon^{1/x} \ge 1-1/x$, I think you are using the definition of limit in this as follows: for each $\sigma>0$ there exists $M_\sigma>0$ such that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x>M_\sigma \implies \epsilon^{1/x}>1-\sigma$. Then, choosing $\sigma=1/x$ (possible because $x \to +\infty$ and so $x>0$), there exists $M_x>0$ such that $x>M_x \implies \epsilon^{1/x} \ge 1-1/x$. The question is: the dependence of $M$ on $x$ doesn't matter in this context?

Comment: Uh, the answer is that I made life too complicated; we don't need to separately have $\epsilon^{1/x}$ and $1 - \frac1x$ as two functions that go to $1$ as $x \to \infty$. See the edited version of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to Misha's method is that after we substitute $u=t^{x}$ and get $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{xt^{x}}{1+t^{x}}dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+u}du$$ It's enough to show that the integrand converges uniformly in order to swap the limit and the integral (Why?). 
You can easily check that $\frac{u^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+u}$ converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{1+u}$, so $$\underset{x\to \infty}{\lim}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+u}du=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+u}du=\ln(2)$$

$\textbf{Edit}$: As the comment below pointed out this doesn't work because there is no uniform convergence.

Comment: I don't think $\frac{u^{1/x}}{1+u}$ *does* converge uniformly to $\frac1{1+u}$ as $x \to \infty$, though. For example, there is no uniform lower bound on $x$ that guarantees $\left|\frac{u^{1/x}}{1+u} - \frac1{1+u}\right| < \frac13$ for all $u \in [0,1]$; no matter which $x$ you pick, $u = 4^{-x}$ will not satisfy that inequality.

Comment: What a silly mistake , thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You have dominated convergence, so you can use that instead.